# How to use the Meanjs generator with Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, meanjs

I am trying to use the Yeoman generator "Meanjs". When I enter `yo --help` I get this:

```
Meanjs
meanjs:angular-config:indexjs
meanjs:angular-controller:indexjs
meanjs:angular-directive:indexjs
meanjs:angular-filter:indexjs
meanjs:angular-module:indexjs
meanjs:angular-route:indexjs
meanjs:angular-service:indexjs
meanjs:angular-test:indexjs
meanjs:angular-view:indexjs
meanjs:app:indexjs
meanjs:crud-module:indexjs
meanjs:express-controller:indexjs
meanjs:express-model:indexjs
meanjs:express-route:indexjs
meanjs:express-test:indexjs
```

So apparently the Meanjs generator is installed. However when I try using `yo meanjs` or `yo Meanjs` I get the error

> Error meanjs
>
> You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs installed. You
>   can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then
>   insta ll them with npm install [name]. To see the 15 registered
>   generators run yo with the `--help` option.

Comment: which version of yeoman are you using?

Comment: I am using the newest one, should be version 1.3.3

Comment: Why don't you try to remove yeoman, clean the npm cache and do a global install?

Comment: I did that now but same error occurs...

Comment: It seems I could run for example `meanjs:angular-config:indexjs` but not only `meanjs` but why? And btw yo doctor tells me everything is alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know why but it never worked using only `meanjs` but as soon as I used `meanjs:app:indexjs` it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you "npm install -g generator-meanjs" (where -g is globally and not only for your project)? This should give you all the meanjs (sub)-generators available. Then a "yo meanjs" followed by "grunt" should scaffold the example-app for you. Works perfectly for me.
I am wondering what the ":indexjs" is with your generators. I don't have that...

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem and when I run $ yo doctor
I got this:

✖ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH

running this, solved it for me:

echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc